# Django atomic block for create with an unique field

Tags: django, django-models, atomic

I have a model similar to the following:

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
   my_field = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', unique = True)
```

And the following code to create new instances of the model:

```
with transaction.atomic():
        try:
            instance, _ = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get_or_create(
                           my_field=value)
        except (IntegrityError, OperationalError):
            pass
    return instance
```

As of my understanding, the entire table is locked by the `select_for_update`.
Another alternative would be catching the `UniqueConstraintError` after it occurs.

Is there any way, to avoid having an `UniqueConstraintError`, without locking the entire table?